# Java: matching ArrayList strings to an iterator, and incrementing the integers of a different ArrayList at the same index

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, nested-loops

noob here, so sorry if I say anything dumb.

I'm comparing strings in an ArrayList to an iterator of strings in an iterator of Sets.  When I find a match, I want to grab the index of matched string in the ArrayList and increment that same index in a different ArrayList of integers.  I have something that looks (to me) like it should work, but after this code runs, my integer ArrayList contains mostly -1 with a few 2,1, and 0.

I'm interested in fixing my code first, but I'd also be interested different approaches, so here's the larger picture:  I have a map where the keys are usernames in a social network, and the values are sets usernames of people they follow.  I need to return a list of all usernames in descending order of followers.  In the code below I'm only trying to make an ArrayList of strings (that contains ALL the usernames in the map) that correspond with a different ArrayList of integers like:

```
usernamesList ... numberOfFollowers
theRealJoe ... 7
javaNovice ... 3
FakeTinaFey ... 3
```

etc

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    //edit: this map is populated.  It's a parameter of the method I'm trying to write.
    List<String> usernamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //populate usernamesList with all strings in map         

    Iterator<Set<String>> setIter = map.values().iterator();
    Iterator<String> strIter;
    int strIterIndex = 0;
    int w = 0;
    List<Integer> numOfFollowers = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    //initialize all elements to 0.  not sure if necessary
    for (int i = 0; i < usernamesList.size(); i++) {
        numOfFollowers.add(0);
    }

    while (setIter.hasNext()) {

        Set<String> currentSetIter = setIter.next();
        strIter = currentSetIter.iterator();

        while (strIter.hasNext()) {

            String currentstrIter = strIter.next();

            if (usernamesList.contains(currentstrIter)) {

                strIterIndex = usernamesList.indexOf(currentstrIter);
                numOfFollowers.set(strIterIndex, numOfFollowers.indexOf(strIterIndex) +1);
                w++;
                System.out.println("if statement has run " + w + " times." );

            } else {

                throw new RuntimeException("Should always return true.  all usernames from guessFollowsGraph should be in usernamesList");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You map does not have any values so this code `while (setIter.hasNext()) {` will not be entered into

Comment: map actually does have keys and values.  Sorry if it's confusing.  I included the map constructor so you'd know what my map was called.

Comment: `Map<String, Set<String>> map = HashMap<String, Set<String>>();` map does not have any values

Comment: Are you trying to do the EdX course on java? ;)

Comment: Haha, yup.  I wrote all my other methods which are passing their tests, but this one is stubborn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everyhing looks ok, except this one:

```
numOfFollowers.set(strIterIndex, numOfFollowers.indexOf(strIterIndex) +1);
```

When you do numOfFollowers.indexOf, you are looking for the **index** of an element that has a value strInterIndex. What you want, is the **value** (follower count) of an element with index strIterIndex:

```
numOfFollowers.set(strIterIndex, numOfFollowers.get(strIterIndex) +1);
```

I would also suggest using int[] (array) instead of a list of indices. It would be faster and more straightforward.

Oh, one more thing: correct the "fake" constructors please, they won't work since there is no "new" keyword after the assignment...